# eliminar caracteres de un texto en python

Tags: python-3.x

tengo el siguiente string:

```
a = "/casa/coche-je"
```

quiero extraer eliminar todo el contenido y dejar solo coche:

```
a = "coche"
```

he probado con replace pero se me queda muy largo hay alguna forma de simplificar esto:

```
a.replace("/","").replace("localidad","").replace("-","")
```

Comment: Prueba esto `print('/"');` esto te imprime las dos sin los backslash pero puedes utilizar find si sabes cual es la palabra que llega así  `variable.find("coche")`

Comment: ¿Cuál es el criterio por el que seleccionas con qué te quedas? ¿Todo lo que haya entre el último `/` y el siguiente `-`? Por otro lado, la expresión que pones al final no producirá "coche", sino "casacocheje",( o "cocheje" asumiendo que en lugar de "localidad" quisiste poner "casa")

Comment: hay bastantes string con lo cual no me serviria no se cual es la palabra que va esta llegando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que la regla sea "La palabra comprendida entre el último `/` y el siguiente `-` tras éste", puedes sacarlo con algunos `.split()`:

```
a = "/casa/coche-je"
palabra = a.split("/")[-1].split("-")[0]
```

Comment: no me sirve porque la etrucura del string puede variar por ejemplo ` "/casa/-je-coche-javi"`

Comment: Entonces quizás deberías ser más específico en cuanto a qué casos te pueden aparecer y con qué criterio extraes la "palabra clave". No te pido el código o algoritmo, sino una especificación escrita como la que puse al principio de mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza expresiones regulares.

```
import re
cadena = re.sub('[/-]+', '', re.search(r'(\/[\w]+-)', texto).group(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Si la palabra a extraer es siempre la misma, en este caso "coche"

```
txt = "/casa/-je-coche-javi"
ubication = txt.find("coche")
txt = txt[ubication:ubication+5]
```

Ahora txt es igual a 'coche'

Answer (score 0):

vale lo he conseguido hacer:

```
re.sub("/|casa","",a).replace("-"," ")
```

Comment: Pero esto no hace lo que pedías en la pregunta. El resultado no sale "coche", sino "cocheje". Simplemente eliminas los guiones

Comment: Y por ende hace que todas las respuestas, salvo la tuya se encuentren en lo correcto...